# C# Convert SQL data into a list without using any framework

Tags: c#, sql

I am converting data from sql into a list of PersonModel. But my question is: is there a faster way ( less code ) to get this done without using any framework / dapper. **LINQ is ALLOWED.**

( The code right now is just working fine, but maybe it can be done in a simpler way ).

This is the code I have right now:

```
public List<PersonModel> GetPerson_All()
{
    var people = new List<PersonModel>();

    //Get the connectionString from appconfig
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
    {
        connection.Open();

        //Using the stored procedure in the database.
        using (var command = new SqlCommand("dbo.spPeople_GetAll", connection))
        {
            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                //With a while loop, going trough each row to put all the data in the PersonModel class.
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var person = new PersonModel();

                    person.Id = (int)reader["Id"];
                    person.FirstName = (string) reader["FirstName"];
                    person.LastName = (string)reader["LastName"];
                    person.EmailAdress = (string)reader["EmailAddress"];
                    person.CellphoneNumber = (string)reader["CellphoneNumber"];

                    //Add the data into a list of PersoModel
                    people.Add(person);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return people;
}
```

With ( dapper ) you can put all the data inmediatly to a list. Is something like this possible without dapper?

```
public List<PersonModel> GetPerson_All()
{
    List<PersonModel> output;
    using (var connection = new SqlConnection(GlobalConfig.CnnString(db)))
    {
        output = connection.Query<PersonModel>("dbo.spPeople_GetAll").ToList();
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would probably be a better fit for this question

Comment: Why do you think libraries like Dapper *exist*? it's exactly to cut down on boilerplate code like this.

Comment: *SQL query* (stored procedure in the question) is the bottleneck of the routine; that's why any other implementations will not be *much faster*

Comment: @JeroenMostert I know? but I am not allowed to use something like dapper

Comment: Why are you not allowed to use dapper?

Comment: @Alegou20: you can always write your own micro-ORM `T Map<T>(DataReader) where T : new` that creates and initializes a new object from a `DataReader` using reflection. This is only a few lines of code. It is terrifically slow, however -- optimizing it results in much more code, so much more that you'd make it a library and call it Dapper.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is not an more optimal way to do this then to use a method or mapper library like Dapper or Entity Framework: that is the entire reason such libraries exist.

If you have repeating code blocks like this, but don't want to use external libraries, you can try to refactor this to a method which executes a statement, iterates over the result and instantiates and fills objects.